# Can you help me with the time complexity of this Python code?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, union

I have written this code and I think its time complexity is O(n+m) as time depends on both the inputs, am I right? Is there a better algorithm you can suggest?

The function return the length of union of both the inputs.

```
class Solution :

    def getUnion(self,a,b,):
        p= 0
        lower, greater = a,b
        if len(a)>len(b):
            lower,greater = b,a

        while p< len(lower): # O(n+m)
            if lower[p] in greater:
                greater.remove(lower[p])
            p+=1
        return len(lower+greater)

print(Solution().getUnion([1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,54,67]))
```

Comment: Why would you want to bold all the text? And please replace `'` with `\`` in the code block

Comment: this is my first qsn on stack so i am not that good with it.

Comment: We won't answer the question until you prove that it's worth answering. And use formal speech please.

Comment: its edited now.

Comment: What the code should do? Edit the question again.

Comment: C'mon, don't swear, and I still do not get what the function should do. Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: Please be more precise. On this forum, questions must concern a well defined problem and the author must add what he tried so far + the part of code which gives the error. Please provide all this information, this is the best way to get help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  is the shorter length, and  the longer (or both are equal), then the `while` loop will iterate  times.

Inside a single iteration of that loop an `in greater` operation is executed, which has a time complexity of O() -- for each individual execution.

So the total time complexity is O().

The correctness of this algorithm depends on whether we can assume that the input lists only contain unique values (each).

You can do better using a set:

```
return len(set(a + b))
```

Building a set is O( + ), and getting its length is a constant time operation, so this is O( + )